# PySpark: Group by two columns, count the pairs, and divide the average of two different columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with several columns, some of which are labeled PULocationID, DOLocationID, total_amount, and trip_distance. I'm trying to group by both PULocationID and DOLocationID, then count the combination each into a column called "count". I also need to take the average of total_amount and trip_distance and divide them into a column called "trip_rate". The end DF should be:

| PULocationID | DOLocationID | count | trip_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 422 | 1 | 5.2435 |
| 3 | 27 | 4 | 6.6121 |

Where (123,422) are paired together once for a trip rate of $5.24 and (3, 27) are paired together 4 times where the trip rate is $6.61.

Through reading some other threads, I'm able to group by the locations and count them using the below:

`df.groupBy("PULocationID", 'DOLocationID').agg(count(lit(1)).alias("count")).show()`

OR I can group by the locations and get the averages of the two columns I need using the below:

`df.groupBy("PULocationID", 'DOLocationID').agg({'total_amount':'avg', 'trip_distance':'avg'}).show()`

I tried a couple of things to get the trip_rate, but neither worked:

`df.withColumn("trip_rate", (pyspark.sql.functions.col("total_amount") / pyspark.sql.functions.col("trip_distance")))`
`df.withColumn("trip_rate", df.total_amount/sum(df.trip_distance))`

I also can't figure out how to combine the two queries that work (i.e. count of locations + averages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this as an example input DataFrame:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|PULocationID|DOLocationID|total_amount|trip_distance|
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|         123|         422|      10.487|            2|
|           3|          27|     19.8363|            3|
|           3|          27|     13.2242|            2|
|           3|          27|      6.6121|            1|
|           3|          27|     26.4484|            4|
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

You can chain together the `groupBy`, `agg`, and `select` (you could also use `withColumn` and `drop` if you only need the 4 columns).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

new_df = df.groupBy(
    "PULocationID",
    "DOLocationID",
).agg(
    F.count(F.lit(1)).alias("count"),
    F.avg(F.col("total_amount")).alias("avg_amt"),
    F.avg(F.col("trip_distance")).alias("avg_distance"),
).select(
    "PULocationID",
    "DOLocationID",
    "count",
    (F.col("avg_amt") / F.col("avg_distance")).alias("trip_rate")
)

new_df.show()
```

```
+------------+------------+-----+-----------------+
|PULocationID|DOLocationID|count|        trip_rate|
+------------+------------+-----+-----------------+
|         123|         422|    1|           5.2435|
|           3|          27|    4|6.612100000000001|
+------------+------------+-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: I swear I commented on this, but I guess I didn't actually add it. Just wanted to make sure I thanked you for your help!